# Large query execution in liquibase

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to update a column in one of my tables through an update query something like the below:

```
update table_name set field='some jsonb operation()';
```

This table has 300k+ rows. I need to update all the rows. I have added a changeset in liquibase with this update query. But when I try to execute, I am getting connection timeout error because the update operation takes 2-3 minutes.
This is a onetime activity. How can I effectively execute the query without timeout error. I thought of splitting the data and apply the update. Will it resolve my issue? or any other better way to do this?

Comment: Sign directly into psql.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a postgresql expert, but if you are doing this with a `<sql>` or `<sqlFile>` change type, it appears that you could prepend the actual query with `SET statement_timeout = 600000` to set the statement timeout for that session. The timeout is in milliseconds, so the example given would be for 10 minutes.

I think the changeset should look something like this:

```
<changeSet id="update-the-things" author="antony">
  <sql splitStatements="true" endDelimiter=";">
    SET statement_timeout = 600000;
    update table_name set field='some jsonb operation()';
  </sql>
</changeSet>
```